# React Native Old Version App does not work in our Latest React Native Version

Tags: react-native

[error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxo0S.png)
React Native Old App - v0.61.5 we use currently and in this Version, we linked external dependencies are manually like (react-native-fcm, react-native-netinfo) now we are trying to build app and again install based on our package.json file manually linked dependencies are throw the error i attached the error screenshot below for your reference

Experts, Please give the solution to build the app successfully also i need to switch these app a react-native latest version

Our old version app wants to Work and How to Switch to Latest React-Native Version

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guidelines provided [here](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) . Select the react native version you are currently using and the latest version that you want to switch to.